# Search for a location in google maps without giving its geo-coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

In my Android app I want to give in an `EditText` field a location/city and by pressing a button I want Google maps to display that specific city.

Is that possible without giving coordinates of the city?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Android - GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class, get Latitude, longitude from address and using it display location on Google Map..

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());    
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
            "Address", 1);

        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
          GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
        }    
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: A Complete Tutorial [Using Google Maps in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Answer (score 4):

Use the Geocoder to get the coordinates then set the map's center to the result.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: Thank you for the advice; I am going to check on it.